# Only able to access one route from routes hierarchy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm attempting to access a route directly from a request, even though another subfolder works the other does not. Repeatedly throwing 404 errors. `/api/getPostList` works but `/post/` or `/post/:title` doesn't work.

I've restructured the code, attempted to change it from a get request to a post request, added `/post/:title` to access an individual post or without a `/` to access the main list.

Server.js contains

```
app.use('/', Routes);
```

routes/index.js contains

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const posts = require('./posts');
const api = require('./api');

router.use('/post', posts);
router.use('/api', api);

module.exports = router;
```

routes/api/index.js contains

```
Api.get('/getPostList', (req, res) => {
    PostModel.find(function (err, post) {
    if (err) return console.log('error: ' + err);
    return res.json({ postList: post});
    });
console.log("Attempted to get post list on /getPost/ route: " + ++postRouteCnt);
});

Api.get('/getPost/:title', getPost);
module.exports = Api;
```

routes/post/index.js contains

```
const Posts = require('express').Router();
const post = require('./post');
const PostModel = require('../../../server/models.js');

let postRouteCnt = 0;
Posts.get('/', (req, res) => {
    PostModel.find(function (err, post) {
        if (err) return console.log('error: ' + err);
        return res.json({ postList: post});
    });
    console.log("Attempted to get post list on /post/ route: " + ++postRouteCnt);
});

Posts.get('/:title', post);

module.exports = Posts;
```

When calling `/post/` I get a 404 `Cannot GET /post/` when I should receive the json response.

EDIT:
Folder structure

```
 Server/

   routes/

     api/

      index.js

      getPost.js (for individual post)

     posts/

      index.js

      post.js (for individual post)

   server.js
```

Comment: can you add your posts/index.js file

Comment: Updated with full posts/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your structure folder, I try to write code with simple code

App.js :

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const Routes = require('./routes/posts/index.js');

app.use('/', Routes);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

.routes/ posts/ index.js :

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const postController = require('./post');

// GET /
router.get('/posts', postController.getPosts);

module.exports = router;
```

.routes/ posts/ post.js :

```js
exports.getPosts = (req,res) => {
  res.send('test');
}
```

Try input http://localhost:3000/posts and its work

You can write any logic in .routes/ posts/ post.js :

Comment: I added the folder structure, I attempted your solution but still received the error

Comment: Restructured all of the code and was still unable to process the get request

Comment: Would you like to share this github project, may be i can check again the code

Comment: Invited as a collaborator. It's on the server branch

Comment: I Have been editing in server.js, routes/ index.js, reoutes/posts/ index.js of your repository project and make sure your require to existing file

Answer (score 0):

try changing it like this

```
Posts.get('/', (req, res) => {
    PostModel.find(function (err, post) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send({ postList: post});
    });
    console.log("Attempted to get post list on /post/ route: " + ++postRouteCnt);
});
```

now try this url

> /post/

Comment: Still unable to get the JSON with the updated solution

Comment: Updated folder structure

Comment: try now I updated the answer again the problem should be your returning statement

Comment: Even with updated return, it still is unable to issue it.